# Backup problem with folder rename (use back in time)

Tags: backup, directory, duplicate, backintime

We use Ubuntu Server (14.04) as file server. As backup solution we use "Back in Time".  I have a general question about making backups, since we are having problems with the folder names from time to time.

For example: Our main folder is called "CUSTOMERS" and is about 4TB large. If someone accidentally renames this folder to "CUSTOMERS1" (just as an example) the backup makes a complete new backup for this new directory.

I know that is what the backup is supposed to do but is there are smart way to avoid these problems?

Comment: Would it be an option to change permissions of that folder so no one can rename it by accident anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Change the ownership of `CUSTOMERS` parent folder to `root` and remove write permissions for other users. This way no one can rename the folder by accident anymore.

```
sudo chown root:root /path/to/parent
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/parent
```